# Are code lenses still available in Visual Studio 2022 (17.6.5)?

Tags: f#, visual-studio-2022

I use Visual Studio Professional 2022 (17.6.5).

Code lenses used to go a bit mad in older versions so I turned them off. I thought I'd have another go, but they seem to be gone. Are they still available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it was removed. There are some linked tickets here that describe ongoing work to replace it: https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/issues/14256

Comment: great- not...its not clear whether code hints really does do the same as code lens